# Invalid config file in clean install - missing configuration section 'contactRepository'

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore7

I have done the following:

- installed a clean Sitecore 7.5 instance
- added the relevant asp.net web forms controls and pages to support the site
- imported and published a content tree from an old application

Visiting the base site url yields a YSOD with the error message:

> Could not find configuration node: contactRepository

Now I understand what this means - there's an expected configuration section that is missing. Adding an empty element `contactRepository` yields an expected message that this section is not defined.

What is `contactRepository`, what is its associated configuration section type, what is it for and what values should be specified in it? Alternatively, how can I turn off whatever demands this section to be present?

**edit #1**:

In the `Sitecore.Analytics.config` file in the  node there are the following two lines:

```
<!--This configuration node is obsolete and will be removed in a future version of Sitecore. Use "contactRepository" node to get access to Contact repository--> 
<contactRepository ref="contactRepository"/>
```

1. The comment is total gibberish. Which node? 'Use' how? 'get access' in what sense? How is this different to what's there?
2. replacing with an empty `<contactRepository>` **without** the `ref` attribute, commenting out this node, both nodes, and the whole tracking node makes no difference to the application's behaviour.

Comment: Can you confirm that the `contactRepository` node is present when you go to `Sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`? There might be a few with that name, but the one you want has a lowercase 'c' and should appear directly between the `automationManager`  and `dataAdapterManager`  nodes

Answer (score 2):

Looking at my local Sitecore 7.5 setup the Contact Repository settings should be in your Sitecore.Analytics.config.

The contacts repository settings relate to the new xDB stuff.

Please ensure you have the correct Sitecore.Analytics config files for 7.5.
There should be around 15 config files with new settings for xDB.

Please read this blog post for more information on the new Analytics setup.

https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/getting-to-know-sitecore/posts/2014/10/introducing-the-sitecore-analytics-index

Comment: Thanks. I have read that article, and it doesn't help. I'm not interested in analytics, so turning it off would be satisfactory, but `Analytics.Enabled="false"` makes no difference to the application's behaviour. I've added what I've found in Sitecore.Analytics.config to my question.

Comment: You'll probably have to go through all your configs and remove the references to analytics. But to be honest there is no point in using Sitecore 7.5 if you are not using xDB and the new Analytics features. You might as well use 7.2.

Comment: It's not my choice, and if it's useful, we probably will end up using it, but there isn't time right now to even consider it. I just need to get this broken site working in 7.5.

Comment: How did you go about installing the Sitecore instance? I've installed Sitecore 7.5 rev. 141003 using Sitecore Instance Manager with no issues at all - all the config should be setup straight out of the zip file. For the mean time just go with all the analytics config enabled. You don't have to setup MongoDB just to get the basics working, but it only takes a minute to set it up.

Comment: I don't know what Sitecore Instance Manager is. I just used the installation wizard, and admittedly leaving that instance completely clean gives me a content editor that works, and a 'welcome to sitecore' homepage. Something that I've published over the top is the trigger for this behaviour, and my preference is to fix it rather than wipe it out, but fixing entails knowing what's wrong.

Comment: The same question asked on the [Sitecore forums](http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=67264#67264) has yielded some advice which sounds helpful, but as I mention, doing what he suggests makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: What exactly have you published over the top of in your clean instance? Did you add content in to the tree? Are you adding custom files to you r clean instance? My advice would be to look at what you are adding to the clean install and add in the files gradually to work out what is causing the issue.

Comment: Check you haven't added the Sitecore.Analytics.config file from an older Sitecore instance.